# Xcode is generating Generic Xcode Archive instead of iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, archiving

I have searched high and low but I am unable to archive an iOS app correctly. The app runs perfectly on the simulator and physical devices but I am not able to submit the app to the AppStore because the app is a Generic Xcode Archive instead of an iOS App.

What I have done:

- Skip install is NO for the main project target
- Skip install is YES for Static Library target
- Alle Copy Headers are in Project
- Installation Directory is /Applications
- Target dependencies are empty

*update* I am not using Cocoapods

*Update* When I compile using terminal:

```
xcodebuild -destination generic/platform=iOS
```

I get the folling error

```
build/iosvr.build/Release-iphoneos/iosvr.build/Objects-normal/armv7/DistortionRenderer.o iosvr/DistortionRenderer.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Comment: "but I am not able to submit the app to the AppStore" What does that mean? What happens when you try?

Comment: Added the title of the Stack Question to the question.

Comment: Have you got deployment credentials correctly configured?

Comment: Yes these are correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode is creating generic xcode archive instead of iOS App Archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369290/xcode-is-creating-generic-xcode-archive-instead-of-ios-app-archive)

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought but this question was solved by removing: Project>Targets>Build Phases>target dependencies