# Xcode 7.2 generating Generic Xcode Archive instead of IPA

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, ipa

I have just taken over of a legacy project written in Objective-C and started extending it with some Swift elements.

The issue is that I cannot archive the app into an IPA - I constantly get generic Xcode archive instead of IPA that I can submit to the app store

[image]

Context : 
 - Cocoa pods version 0.39.0, Xcode version 7.2

- I use cocoapods but the issue was present earlier, when the project didn't use it yet.
- I have tips from other similar issues on stack overflow ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369290/xcode-is-creating-generic-xcode-archive-instead-of-ios-app-archive)) but nothing seems to help.
- 'Skip install' is set to YES on all of the pod building targets. Main project has 'skip install' set to NO.
- When I export the build products the folder contains only MyApp.app
- All of the copy headers are in 'Project' not in 'Public'. I have also tried a configuration with 'Private' but it didn't help.

[image]

- My build scheme :
  [image]
- I have also tried building the entire workspace from command line with the following script :

`xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace clean archive -archivePath build/MyProject
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath "build/MyProject.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/MyProject.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "DistributionProvisioningProfile"`

but I'm getting the following error :

```
error: the archive at path '/pathtotheappfolder/MyProject.xcarchive' is not a single-bundle archive
```

**My main question is - how build it as an IPA?**

**Side question - how do I find out or at least get direction of what is going wrong?**

Update :

When exporting the archive and going to "show package contents" the file structure looks like that :

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try an export then?

Comment: hey - the archive ends up in "other items" and the two only options for exporting is "save as build products" and "export as xcode archive"

Comment: @trojanfoe - iOS Distribution provisioning profile & certificate

Answer (score 1):

For quick result, go to Organizer , right click on archive file and select show in finder. you will get xcarchive, now right click and select show package contents. go to products, go to application, there will be app file.

Now copy that app file and paste it in new folder with name payload. then compress it. then rename it with project_name.ipa

You will get ipa quickly.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Unfortunately the .app file from the package contents in 0 bytes... do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: This solved my issue. This is an old way of creating an IPA file. I suddenly remember this approach which is way back around 2009. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow below steps and you can have your issu resolved :

- In your xcode go to Targets > Build Phases > Target dependencies > Remove it.
- Now again build your api.
- It will work for you.
  Its worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It happens, when you've added a new framework(s) for which you need to edit the **Target > Build Settings** and set the **Skip Install setting to Yes**.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks.
For Framework you need to set Skip Install to YES and for apps you need to set Skip Install to NO.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because my scheme (Edit Scheme) 'archive' build configuration drop down entry was set to 'debug' and not to 'release' - due to a test that I did and forgot that this setting was set.

Thanks
John Goodstadt
XCode 12.1 Oct 2020

Answer (score -2):

Sadly, the only way out of this was to create a new project and move all the files over.

Answer (score -2):

While viewing the Xcode archive (or xcarchive) in Xcode **(8.3.2)** click **Export** on the right hand side. Choose your certificate and a method for export. Then you'll get the ipa.

[image]

[image]

[image]