# XCode Generic Archive instead of iOS app Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

My application suddenly stops creating iOS App Archive, instead it begins creating Xcode Generic Archive.

This is happening after working on changes for a new release of my app, I've added logical, UI changes and some new frameworks.

I reviewed all the **"Skip Install"** flags for my Project, my Target and also the Pod libraries I'm using. Everything is ok. I also made sure the copy header build phase is not including public nor private headers, only project headers. I also checked that the **"Installation path"** is set to a valid path in my project and target, and it's pointing to **Applications**.

I've not target dependencies on my main target nor Copy Files phase.

Please if any one have found other possible things that cause this error I'd really appreciate your help.
FYI I'd already read the following post in StackOverflow:

1. [Cannot generate iOS App archive in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode)
2. [Cannot generate iOS App archive in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode)
3. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html
4. http://pulkitsinghal.blogspot.com.ar/2012/03/wrong-archive-ios-app-archive-vs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending more than 4 hours on this I found what is happening in my case.
Basically, the problem (Xcode generic archive generation instead of app archive) was caused because of the addition of SASS to preprocess my .css file that I'm using with Pixate.

I found some minutes ago that there are new instructions to add SASS, and you can find these here [Adding SASS to iOS](https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-ios/tree/master/themes#compiling-sass)

I had followed the instructions in the Pixate page [to add SASS with Pixate](http://www.pixate.com/blog/2013-01-19-sass/) but these instructions were causing the default.css file to be generated outside my app .ipa file. As I show in the attached image. [image: Generic Archive - > Save Built Products output].

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by OP skip install and installation directory played into it. My issue though was a different one.
i had RUN_DOCUMENTATION_COMPILER set in build settings which lead to creating a generic archive. Make sure this is either removed or set to NO.