# XCode creating Generic Xcode Archive instead of iOS Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

So I know this question has been asked several times before, but none of the other accepted answers solves my problem. I have an Swift/Objective-C Xcode Project that uses CocoaPods. The skip install build setting is set to yes for CocoaPods and no for my main project. When I archive my project, I get a Generic Xcode Archive and when I export the built products to a directory, I see myproject.app and myproject.zip which when I open it has many subfolders inside leading to a derive data folder and another copy of myproject.app.

When I try xcodebuild to export my archive I get the error "not a single bundle archive". Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Which XCode version are you using and which kind of target are you archiving?

Comment: XCode 6.0.1 and I am archiving an iOS App target.

Comment: I have tried the same issue. But After I restart the xcode, clean build and archive it again.. and then it's solved.

Comment: @TonyFungChoiFung Yah, that is the first thing I tried. Didn't work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot generate iOS App archive in xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure what exactly went wrong, but I fixed it by creating a new Xcode project and importing all my code.

Comment: Probably it was related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274921/xcodebuild-archives-all-targets-instead-of-one