# xcodebuild archives all targets instead of one

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I need to archive a specific scheme from my `xcodeproj`. To do this I run

```
xcodebuild archive \
    -scheme $SCHEME \
    -target $TARGET \
    -archivePath $ARCHIVE_PATH
```

Although I **explicitly** define a scheme and target, the resulting `xcarchive` contains both targets and the follow-up IPA export call complains with

```
error: the archive at path '<path>.xcarchive' is not a single-bundle archive
** EXPORT FAILED **
```

Why does `xcodebuild` produce an archive with multiple bundles?

Comment: `scheme` and `target` are mutually exclusive. Could you try passing scheme only?

Comment: Doesn't work either way. Already tried that.

Comment: For others who potentially have this problem, my issue was not setting SKIP_INSTALL to YES for static libraries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a problem with the project's schemes. I created new Schemes by duplicating the original one instead of adding a new one. The resulting scheme then listed 2 targets in the build section instead of one (only god knows why) and Xcode would not let me remove the other target.

Once I removed all schemes and created them from scratch everything worked just fine.

Comment: Can you explain where you meant by listed two targets in the build section? in the scheme->build or in your project settings somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

One more scenario when this happens is when your sub-project(Target dependency) has `Skip Install` set to `No` in build settings.

To find which sub-project, check the content inside the archive. Products folder should have only one product.

In my case a sub-project was a dynamic library and was added in the archive under `/<path to archive>/Products/usr/lib/<library>` path.