# After upgrading to Xcode 6.3, newly built iOS app archives can't be submitted

Tags: ios, xcode

After upgrading to 6.3 and building an archive for my iOS app, the archive appears under "Other Items" and "Submit to App Store" is grayed out.

My archives built prior to upgrading are listed correctly under the name of the app.

I noticed that it works correctly for the Mac version of my app.

I tried changing the iOS version's target name and scheme name to all match the name under iOS Apps in the Organizer but that didn't help (if only things were that simple!).

[image: Archives window]

Comment: Isn't 6.3 a beta? And hence excluded from submission?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman, no, it's not a beta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Resolution from Apple

For example, my app "Tripla" has one main project and one sub-project (Google-API-client: GTL.xcodeproj). In the main project, it has one main target and 4 sub-targets, and in the GTL.xcodeproj, it has 4 targets.

Skip-install in tab "Build Setting" in the main project setting is YES,
but NO in the sub-project and all its sub-targets.

Skip-install in tab "Build Setting" in the main target of the main project is YES, but NO in the rest of sub-targets.

It did solve this issue of my app "Tripla".

[Apple Troubleshoot technotes TN2215](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html)

Comment: I love you Kueiapp <3 Thank you for the perfect link and answer

Comment: I think you have reversed the YES/NO settings. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13620628/510577

Answer (score 5):

Finally I noticed that it was building a "Generic Archive". I consulted this question: [Cannot generate iOS App archive in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode)

My setting for `INSTALL_PATH` ("Installation Directory") was set to `$(HOME)/Applications`. I set it to the default, `/Applications`, and that fixed the issue. I would mark this as a duplicate of the linked question, but someone might encounter the same issue after upgrading Xcode (something obviously changed).

Comment: I haven't had any luck following almost all of the suggestions in the linked response and was forced to downgrade to XCode 6.2.

Comment: @smithclay, that's rough. I'm sorry :( If you haven't already, try exporting the archive and seeing what's inside. Is it just the app, or stuff you didn't expect?

Comment: It's just the app, but there are some weird inconsistencies between the 6.2 and 6.3 version. For instance, the `SwiftSupport` directory isn't in the root of the archive and the `Info.plist` is incomplete (the only keys are `Name`, `SchemeName`, and `CreationDate`).

Comment: Did you ever try upgrading again @smithclay ? If so did it work then? I've just run into this problem too.

Comment: I have the `Installation Directory` set to `/Applications` and I still have the issue, do not thing this is the correct solution.

Comment: For me , it's  that archive contains header files.

    If your app links against a static library, then your archive contains header files because the library probably uses a Headers build phase to export these files as shown in Figure 4. Headers build phases do not work correctly with static library targets when archiving in Xcode. Delete this phase, add a Copy Files build phase to your library, and use it to export your header files. See Copying Files While Building a Product for more information about adding a Copy File build phase to your project.

Comment: FINALLY THE REAL ANSWER

Answer (score 3):

If the above answer doesn't work for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31645306/1792570) is what solved it for me. It might be an issue due to `CocoaPods` updation

Answer (score 2):

Updating to Cocoapods 38.2 and running 'pod install' fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is my case was downgrading cocoapods. Using Xcode 7, and cocoapods 0.39.0.beta.4, downgraded to beta 3.

See this answer for full instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32654636/146738