# XCode 6.3 Produces an Invalid iOS Application Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After upgrading to Xcode 6.3, my existing swift-based Xcode project no longer can create a valid iOS application archive from the command-line or IDE, so I can't submit it to the app store or distribute it.

The command-line build error is as follows:

> Project name does not contain a single–bundle application or contains multiple products. Please select another archive, or adjust your scheme to create a single–bundle application.

It seems only one other person has run into this on SO
("[After upgrading to Xcode 6.3, newly built iOS app archives can't be submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638618/after-upgrading-to-xcode-6-3-newly-built-ios-app-archives-cant-be-submitted)") -- but the extensive workarounds suggested in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode) haven't worked. My build settings have not changed from my 6.2 -> 6.3 project and they appear to be correct. I can still generate a valid archive in Xcode 6.2

**Has anyone else experienced Xcode 6.3 generating invalid application archives, or know of any workarounds?**

#### The contents of the bad archive

The archive artifact that xcode generates (in both debug and release mode) is clearly invalid. The `info.plist` inside the archive is missing critical information and there is no `SwiftSupport` directory in the root of the archive (unless this changed in XCode 6.3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ArchiveVersion</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2015-04-16T19:27:31Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
    <key>SchemeName</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

#### Other potentially interesting stuff

- Project is about 80% swift.
- There's a single application extension.

Comment: Try filing a radar and then posting the number on the developer forums instead of SO, since Apple engineers may see your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, still exists on 6.3.1. I've followed up with Apple Support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this was a regression in Xcode 6.3 -- my Xcode 6.2 `INSTALL_PATH` wasn't working with 6.3 swift projects.

Updating the `project.pbxproj` file did the trick (for both debug and release mode):

`INSTALL_PATH = "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)";`

to

`INSTALL_PATH = /Applications`;