# Xcode 7 GM created generic archive instead of iOS app archive

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently started using Xcode 7 GM.
When I archive my project, I get a generic Xcode archive instead of an iOS archive.

I'ved tried pretty much all the following:

- [xcode is creating generic xcode archive instead of iOS App Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369290/xcode-is-creating-generic-xcode-archive-instead-of-ios-app-archive)
- [Cannot generate iOS App archive in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode)

I compared the contents of a previous successful archive and a different folder structure for some components:

- Swift libraries are inside a sub folder
- The app extension is outside of the .app package
- The info.plist is missing keys

[image]

Has anyone else encountering this problem? If so, did you solve and how?

#### Edit

We are using Cocoapods 0.38.2

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned this, we are using 0.38.2

Comment: I have similar problem with creating iOS archive but version 0.38.2 should be ok. But still you could look into [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4021), mainly `Products directory includes usr/local/include` because it shouldn't.

Comment: @LiborZapletal thanks for the tip, I will look into that issue.

Comment: I just tried using Cocoapods 0.39 beta 4 and it seems to have fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @LiborZapletal I'll wait a little bit and test this with the rest of my team but I'll ping you so you can write an answer and I can accept it so you can claim the ever so important fake internet points.

Comment: Im in the same boat but just upgrading cocoapods didn't work for me, was there anything else you did that might have had a side effect @bensarz?

Comment: @AndrewPlummer I mainly played around with skip install, recreating my certs and prov profiles, deleted derived data, I recreated the schemes, I think that's it.

Comment: Thanks @bensarz I got mine working by changing my cocoapods version to: Cocoapods 0.39 beta 3, version beta 4 did not work for me.

Comment: @AndrewPlummer I tried again yesterday and cocoapods beta 4 fixes it for me but that's not to say that this problem is caused by only one problem.

Comment: I still have the problem with 0.38.2 as well as the 0.39 beta 4. beta 3 doesn't even allow me to make a `pod update`. I am pretty much lost and have no idea how to fix my project :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP here.
The members of my team all tried Cocoapods' beta and it fixed the problem for us. Therefore I'm going to accept my own answer.

Although it might fix the problem, I believe Christian Navelot's answer to not be scalable and certainly not manageable within a team.

Also, all of us tried using the cp beta without removing the `Copy Pod Resources` build phase. This means that I won't be accepting Todd Anderson's answer either.

We are not using static libraries either, we are using frameworks (aka `use frameworks!` inside the Podfile).

Thanks to all for contributing to this question. Looks like we all got put into the same boat by Xcode 7!
Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

I add the same problem : an old Xcode project, Xcode 7 (not the GM, the App Store version) and Cocoapods.
I have been tinkering a lot, tried Cocoapds 0.39 b3 and b4 without success, changed params in Build Settings, but finally - for me - the problem was shown by mrezk in https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4021 :

> Missing ApplicationProperties in Info.plist

As I'm not used to tinker with Info.plist and these keys, I've found in the Apple Dev forums a very useful answer : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17063

In summary, for info.plist newbies like me ;) :

1. Archive your project
2. Organizer will show a Generic Xcode Archive
3. Right Click, Show in finder
4. Right Click, Show Package Contents
5. Open the Info.plist file in a XML editor
6. As [mochs](https://forums.developer.apple.com/people/mochs) indicates, add these lines in the  section :

```
<key>ApplicationProperties</key>  
<dict>  
  <key>ApplicationPath</key>  
  <string>Applications/<<APP_NAME>>.app</string>  
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>  
  <string><<BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER>></string>  
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>  
  <string><<YOUR_MARKETING_NUMBER>></string>  
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>  
  <string><<YOUR_BUILD_NUMBER>></string>  
  <key>SigningIdentity</key>  
  <string>iPhone Distribution: <<CERTIFICATE_NAME>> (<<CERTIFICATE_ID>>)</string>  
</dict>
```

and replace the tags with your own values.

Save, close Xcode, double click the archive : it should open in the Organizer as a iOS Type Archive.

Thanks to [mrezk](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4021) and [mochs](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17063) for the solution.

Comment: And, I can confirm first hand that the archive receives a 'Submission Successful' when uploaded to the App Store.

Comment: I had the same exact issue, and this also resolved the behavior for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me too!  Nice job!

Comment: How do I fix my project so that future builds don't all have this same problem too

Comment: I hope they'll fix Xcode 7 soon, seems a problem when the project is archived

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Waiting for submission approval now :)

Comment: Downgrade CocoaPods, run `pod install` again and rebuild everything. I find it way easier than fixing the plist file every time. It seems to be an issue with the latest CocoaPods betas. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, and a great alternative to other answers that require pod update which updates your cocoapods.

Answer (score 3):

In my case clearing the "Installation Directory" build setting in all static libraries fixed the issue. It was set to "/usr/local/lib" before.

When using "Save Built Product" as export method the Products folder got these sub directories. That's what pointed me in this direction.

I'm using cocoapods 0.38.2.

Comment: Worked for me in addition to set "Skip install" to NO in the Pods Build settings.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers mentioned here were temporary fixes, but each required manual effort, either after every archive or after every `pod install`.

The new, better solution, is to update cocoapods to the latest version and remove your 'Copy Pod Resources' build phase from each app extension.

See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4021 for more information.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I will retest this this week and close this question once and for all if all works out as expected! Cheers!

Comment: Actually the latest version (0.39.x) was the problem for me. As the link you posted points out, this is an issue with the latest betas. I completely uninstalled them and rebuilt everything with 0.38.2, which worked. But thanks for posting the link :)

Comment: I never use the cocoapods betas and was running into this issue with both .38 and .39, so maybe there was something else going on too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with XCode7.1.1 and an app project with WatchKit Extension.
I fixed the issue by the following step

- Open Build Settings of my app target and set **NO** to "Skip Install".
- Open Build Settings of my WatchKit Extension target and set **YES** to "Skip
  Install"
- Open Build Settings of my WatchKit App target and set **YES** to "Skip
  Install"

Then I could make iOS archive.