# Xcode 7 try to archive an ios app with library

Tags: ios, xcode7, archive

When I try to archive my project which include a library I get only generic archive type instead of IOS type.
I manage the scheme so my library would be in my main project container, I changed the skip install in the library to "YES".(in the main project set to NO but tried also to YES).
Why this keep happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work?

Go to Xcode preferences and make sure to download all provisional profiles. Quit Xcode & restart your computer then try deleting (backup if you want) your library - developer - Xcode - Archives folder and DerivedData folder. Archive

Try this if the above doesn't work:
[Xcode 7 GM created generic archive instead of iOS app archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524011/xcode-7-gm-created-generic-archive-instead-of-ios-app-archive)