# Adding swift to obj-c project causes Generic archive to be generated?

Tags: ios, xcode

After adding Swift support to an existing Obj-C Xcode 6.4 project it's now generating Generic Xcode Archives instead of iOS App Archives.

The commit that broke it is here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/Tropos/commit/57da8e4

What can I do to have this generate iOS App Archives again?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like my "Installation Directory" was set incorrectly. It was set to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` when it should be set to `Applications`. Manually doing this or removing the custom setting does this.

[image: xcode screenshot]

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921685/1720355 for original answer/explanation.