# Submit and Validade button disabled on archive

Tags: app-store, xcode5, app-store-connect

i'm trying to create my archive to send my app to the store but the "validate" button and "submit to app store" are disabled.

What i'm doing wrong?

[image]

package content
[image]

target:
[image]

Comment: Just archive again and it works. :) Nothing to do anything else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've solved the problem using it:

"I found the Installation Directory build setting and noticed it was set to a custom path in my project. I simply deleted it (setting it to its generic value of /Applications) and the next Build -> Archive I did worked as expected and gave me a proper iOS App Archive."

**source:** [Cannot generate iOS App archive in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode)

Answer (score 2):

The type of your archive `Generic Xcode Archive`is incorrect.

To debug :

1. Try opening it (right Click > Show In finder > Right Click > Show package content...) to see what is in there appart from your app
2. Look in your project Build Phases what are the Target Dependencies

I might be able to help more with this information

Comment: Ok, i'll check it when i get home and post here the result

Comment: Are you sure this image is the content of your .xcarchive fil? Do you have only one schme you are archiving ?Using the *Product* > *archive*http://i.imgur.com/OWvascc.png menu ?