# Fabric Crashlytics Beta keeps asking to distribute old build

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am trying to distribute an app to my Beta Testers using Fabric and whenever I try to archive the build it keeps asking me to distribute older build [1.5.2 (8.0)] whenever I archive a new build the build.

I want to distribute 1.6 (31) and not 1.5.2 (8.0)

Here is a screenshot of my Xcode Organizer

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @jrg Check the answer I posted below. I referred to another question on SA and got it working. Do note that I followed both. Hope it works for you too
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34342497/1781918

Comment: I am not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13620628/1781918) worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode) thread helped me resolve this issue

**[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32612295/1781918)**

If you're using CocoaPods as well as WatchKit or a Today Extension, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4021) on the CocoaPods repo explaining what your problem might be.

The **solution** for me was to remove the `Copy Pod Resources` phase from the WatchKit Extension and Today Extension targets under `Build Phases`. The project compiled and archived as expected once I did this.

Hope this helps someone, this had me stumped for an entire day!

---

**[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32662905/1781918)**

If you export the archive, open it and see `/urs/local/include` in *Products* try [this suggestion](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4119#issuecomment-):

> In each pod, under `Packaging`, `Private Headers Folder Path` and `Public Headers Folder Path` is set to `/usr/local/include`. If I clear them then I get a valid archive.

[image]

Worked for me after upgrading my React Native app to `0.11.0`, Xcode `7` and CocoaPods `0.39.0.beta.4`.

Answer (score 10):

Often have the same problem – crashlytics is suggesting to distribute an older version when I just archived a newer version.

I found out that there is a hard to find drop down menu to display all archived versions. Select **ARCHIVES** item and then distribute the desired version.

[image]

Comment: I have noticed that before and upload all my builds from there only. But my issue was not related to this. It was some archiving issue with Xcode which I have explained in my answer on this thread