# Can't create ipa from Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, ipa

My project was initially build with the early version of Xcode.

Even with Xcode 6 I was able to export the app (Ad Hoc, ipa file).

After that we started to use continuous integration & upload of builds to iTunes.

Also, I have deleted my working copy.

Recently, I have to make fixes in the project.I checked out the source code,   updated my Xcode to the latest version - Xcode 7, updated the project.

But now when I am archiving the app, it goes under unknown app in Organizer, I can't create ipa ( Validate button is not active).
[image]

For some reasons the app, in the Organizer doesn't have a valid identifier

I tried to use a new

> PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER

and directly to set correct bundle ID, but I still have 2 items, instead of one app.

Comment: It's fu..ing Xcode, yes) Try to clean project, delete derived data, delete all provisions and add them again and then archive again. Cleaning and removing derived data helped me many times in different situations)

Comment: Have you tried the first two steps as given in the link below? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620628/4247686

Answer (score 0):

- In build setting under build option Disable bitcode.
- In build setting under deployment set false to skip install.

Comment: Try to archive by cleaning or by force quitting the xcode.

Comment: didn't work for me I have both flags active. This happens to a old app confirmed.