# xcode uploading issue when build is prepare for itune store

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, xcode7

i have an app having no issue when run on iphone simulator but when upload to the itune store it have validate and upload to the app store button disabled as shown in image

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The type of your archive Generic Xcode Archiveis incorrect.

To debug :

1. Try opening it (right Click > Show In finder > Right Click > Show package content...) to see what is in there appart from your app
2. Look in your project Build Phases what are the Target Dependencies

source: [Cannot generate iOS App archive in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode)

source: [Application Archiving in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html)

Comment: i have update my question as i follow your instruction i have this two files as shown in image

Comment: See the installation Directory build setting and check it is set to a custom path in your project. if it is then simply deleted it (setting it to its generic value of /Applications) and the next Build -> Archive. So try this.

Comment: @SoftCoder please see the link i added in my answer, and follow as mentioned in that technical note.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it could be related to how you signed the IPA.
Check you provisioning profiles and certificate in your release configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your package as `save for iOS app store deployment`,
and upload with `application loader`.

`application loader`can be open in `XCode -> open developer tool`.

Comment: see the image i have this two options @

jiangjiefs

Comment: ok,i didnt meet this problem before. guess maybe your subproject in your main project cause this problem. you can try to build your subproject into a library and then replace the subproject with the library.