# Xcode 10 Archives to 'Other Items' instead of 'MacOS Apps'

Tags: xcode, macos, quicklook, spotlight

This was working perfectly - before I upgraded to Xcode 10 that is. My app has a Quicklook and a Spotlight plugin integrated into it.  These plugins are built separately and then, in the Build Phase, copied (two Copy Files) with the following settings:

```
Destination: Wrapper
Subpath: Contents/Library/<QuickLook|Spotlight>
Code Sign on Copy
```

Now, when I attempt to Archive in order to submit my App to the Mac App Store, my application archive to 'Other Items' instead of 'MacOS Apps'.

If I remove my plugins then it will archive correctly - but (obviously) I don't want to do that since this functionality is critical.

Has anyone seen this problem before?  Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot generate iOS App archive in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting generic Xcode build.
This may happen, if you're using nested applications, static libraries, frameworks or headers.

You should set `Skip install` to`YES` in build settings for your plugins.

More [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2215/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011221-CH1-HD1)

Comment: Perfect.  Just the ticket.  Now I just need to work out how to 'Harden' Sparkle.

Answer (score 2):

To be a bit more precise than just randomly setting Skip install on any target:

Check the contents of the .xcarchive, Xcode reports it as a generic archive when there's more than one item in Products/Applications. It should contain only your application.

After finding the extra items there, you can then know for which target you should set "Skip Install" to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but when I look inside the archive, found the app and the documentation (doccarchive).
Fix: Disable "Build documentation during 'Build'" flag (only for Release).