# Xcode - Archive product goes to Other Items instead of iOS Apps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, archive

I am using XCode 11.2.1 and out of nowhere the archives for deployment appear in the Other Items category, instead of iOS Apps (in Organizer). I am using my custom static framework and what I found that this may be the issue, but for a while, like a month or so after I created and used my framework, I had no problems with deploy  (I am also using CocoaPods, but that was ok).

I have tried a lot of things like here: 
[Xcode 10 Archives to 'Other Items' instead of 'MacOS Apps'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653706/xcode-10-archives-to-other-items-instead-of-macos-apps)

and it worked for a few times, but now, with multiple cleanings, deleting derived data, etc, nothing works.

Here there is a reference to header files (but I have never changed anything about them when it worked): https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2215/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011221-CH1-PROJ

The problem is that the help link about Copy files is not working and also (I cannot find "Copy files" section in Build phases - maybe it was renamed), the Xcode version is different (I found other posts on StackOverflow) so I cannot manage to make them work (I am pretty new to Xcode and C++ / Obj C / Swift and it is difficult to manage those options if I cannot really understand the references (or with missing help/explanations, which I don't know where to look for)

I used this to create and use my framework: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios (and different other links but very similar to this one)

Can someone please provide some help regarding the steps needed to make your app deployable to AppStore while using my custom framework? I can provide other information and screenshots if needed. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Is there a way to check what is different between the creation of the last archive that worked and the new one that I cannot deploy?

After archiving my app I also exported it and explored it in Finder (as instructed here: stackoverflow.com/a/15120289/1215791) So there is no libraries folder.  It seems that the problem is not related to forgetting set Skip Install to YES for something.

Comment: I can't reasonably help you with the whole problem, but i can tell you that "Copy files" is an optional build phase. Click the little + in left top corner of the Phases list and you should see "New Copy Files Phase".

Comment: Ok, but I cannot find a way to use this option. The link for help in apple documentation is not working: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH14-SW1

Answer (score 2):

Check the contents of the .xcarchive, this happens when there's more than one item in Products/Applications. It should contain only your application.

After finding the extra items there, you can then know for which target you should set "Skip Install" to Yes.

Answer (score 1):

This just started happening with Xcode 13.3.
Turns out that I was adding the DocC to the Products/Applications directory. I turned off the flag for compiling documentation ("Build Documentation during 'Build'"), and it started working again.

[image: Showing the flag as "off"]

Comment: Turns out this appeared in the latest Xcode and stopped our builds from being published to the AppStore. 

Ive set it just to build during debug builds. If you still need documentation