# Flutter - iOS; app is run but cannot archive

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I had a strange situation when my app is run via command line (flutter run) and in xCode but when I choose "Generic iOS Device" to archive, I got an error:

> 'shared_preferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.h' file not found

I tried different methods related with plugins problem, recommended in Github and here. For example, this one:

1. xCode -> Project -> Clean
2. deleted Podfile.lock and directory Pods
3. pod install
4. flutter clean, flutter run

Everything works smoothly until I try to archive.

This is my Podfile (I have done it based on this example: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15409#issuecomment-387063765)

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter packages get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

pre_install do |installer|
  # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289
  Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
    # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7463
    target.headers_build_phase.files.each do |file|
      file.settings = { 'ATTRIBUTES' => ['Public'] }
    end
  end
end
```

This is my flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.13, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Also, I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715211/cannot-generate-ios-app-archive-in-xcode) about problems with archiving in xCode but did not find answer.

Do you have any ideas what to do?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by running `flutter build ios` and then archiving start working. Flutter build ios download and upgraded few build tools. I think they were causing this isse.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary solution was to build with command line but the issue with building in Xcode still exist

Answer (score 0):

Delete all **Pod files** inside **/ios** directory then run the following commands in /ios directory:

```
sudo pod init
sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to delete your ios folder and regenerate the project and see whether the error disappears or not:

> flutter create .

Hope this help, I have met crash on a project for a few weeks ago since the new update with Xcode 11.4 and this method help me